It takes a long time to load a vb.net program from a vba shell and we do it multiple times. Is there a way to speed this up?
I have an accounting application that runs a stripped down version of VBA.  When I perform more indepth functions to a data entry, I will load a VB.net (WIndows forms) program sending relevant parmaters.
In the program we allow screens, changes and updates that would be very difficult in VBA.
We are finding that the loading these programs takes a long time and causes the user to spend a substational number of seconds waiting for the process to complete.  Some users experience less wait time than others.
My inclination is that it is the load time of these programs that causes the lag time.  Is there a way to verify this is the problem.
For example, our order entry process might add a minute or so of lag time for each order entered.
And, if it is the problem, is there a way to load the programs once when log in and quickly reaccess them upon demand.  I thought about services but they do not allow user interface and we are using screens.

There isn't a lot to go on here. Check that you have sufficient RAM, but there isn't going to be a lot you can do to optimize an MS Office based solution. the .net interop stuff for office is and always will be slow. thats Office's fault, not .Net's.

Yes, all programs can be loaded at startup -- just put a shortcut in "C:\Users\All Users\Start Menu\Programs" or in "C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs". Of course, that delays startup.

Once the program is loaded, how do I execute the loaded program.  BTW this is not a office program.  The accounting software as a stripped down VBA running behind the screens.  And it is accessed by events being triggered.  (Maybe that is the answer to my own question. We set up events that we trigger? But, if there are perferred methods, could you share with me?  Thanks

As far as other things to go on, we increased ram, some machines are native windows 10,some were upgraded from windows 7.  It is true that some machines behave worse than others so I am compiling a table.   But, I am pretty sure if we took away the .net program loading we would make substantial improvements.  Thanks much.

so why don't you just run the .net program before you launch your accounting application and then just ... don't close it? also what are "screens"?

Screens are  the data entry and navigation UI (Forms).    In answer to your question about launching early,  I am kind of hung up about how I would manage an interface between a running program and my calling VBA.   The loading of the program also enables me to enter the program (entry point) with parameters and by shutting it down, I return back to the calling program and cointinue executio there.  If you know where I can find an example of how to enter the  running program and then return the control back to the calling vba, I am missing that experience.   Thanks for your response.

Without more details I don't know that we can help really, besides generic suggestions to "run more things earlier". The problem with this is that on your clearly aging hardware (even Windows 10 is relatively old) running more things slows everything down, so your trade off is "everything always slow" and "slow start to one specific program". I'd also suggest that a VBA-written product is likely to be quite old, not capable of taking advantage of modern code or processing advantages, and finding another product is likely something that should be considered.

Another point: When additional information is requested, add that information to your question. The more and clearer information in your question, the better people will be able to understand the situation and the more likely you are to get good answers. Using the EDIT button is strongly recommended here.
